# How to check if my iPhone's connection is being throttled?

Tags: iphone, performance

AT&T now throttles the connection speeds for those on the unlimited plan. How can I know if my iPhone's connection is being throttled or if I'm just getting poor speed due to other reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether your internet connection is slow may have several reasons:

- poor, instable connection
- geographic location
- total traffic on the network
- you've reached your cap (see contract)

For the normal users it's difficult to determine what the exact reason is. Especially in dense areas, the promised speed is not reached sometimes because the total traffic of all users is very high. Where I live, the same network is used by different providers, adding additional complications.

In order to judge if your network connection slower than usual, you should test and record your network speed for several times throughout a month.

You can use **[Mobile Speed Test](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/speedtest.net-mobile-speed/id300704847?mt=8)** to get stats about **Download**, **Upload** and **Ping**. You can use this data to check the speed you've been promised by your provider. Check your contract to see what speed you have been promised. Most contracts throttle the speed after you have reached a cap.

[image]

---